# Running Spark Client outside EMR cluster and connecting to YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have the following scenario:

1. I work at a large corporation.
2. We have an EMR cluster with Spark/Hadoop stack running on YARN.
3. I can SSH to the master node of the cluster and from there, I can create Spark shells or spark-submit jobs to the Spark cluster without any issues.
4. However, I would like to run Spark client on my company's server because all of our codebase sits there and I, thus have the ability to do an active development on that server as I can git clone and push to the repository that sits on my company's server. I don't want to transfer all of the company code over to master node of AWS to do active development.
5. So, how do I modify Spark settings to use AWS's YARN as the resource manager?
6. I tried copying Spark installation (in `/user/lib/spark`) and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` (in `/etc/hadoop/conf`) from the master node of EMR cluster over to my company's server, but Spark does not recognize YARN.

Thanks.

Edits: Changed 'driver' to 'client' in subject line and in the body.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in standalone mode, but not in yarn mode.

When spark is run on yarn mode, it doesn't have control over where executor, AM and driver will be sitting.

Yarn checks the memory usage on each task node, and data availability and spins these components where it computes as ideal.

So, even if you manage to add your external node to yarn (you can do that obviously), just setup proper configuration and run admin refresh on yarn's resource manager.
But, than also, you cannot ensure, where will your spark driver be running.

**Update**
It is perfectly possible to do that. Here are the things you will need to do.

1. Setup livy server. This is a rest based Spark communication server that talks with yarn. If you have distributions like cloudera or HDP, it is just matter of clicking some buttons on UI.
2. Setup GUI like Zappelin or Apache Hue, and configure it correctly to communicate with livy server.

Livy server is going to be in AWS on open port your local system or external node can talk to. Hue or Zappelin can be on your external node.